# how to remove vuetify's v-row inbuilt css property?

Tags: vuetify.js

I am using vuetify v2.0 in my project, in that I want to remove margin of **v-row** tag, so i applied style margin: 0 !important to that property but it still didn't work, so after that i also tried ma-0 which is known as spacing helpers as given in vuetify docs but that too doesn't help me.

I want to ask is there any idea of completely removing it from v-row..

I will share a image for better understandment of problem

[image]

But when i uncheck the margin property which is inbuilt in v-row then my problem get solved

see in below image :-

[image]

You can see that when i uncheck the checkbox of margin in v-row inbuilt css property then only it is getting removed and applied to my website.

Any help would be appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `no-gutters` property to your `v-row` like this :

`<v-row no-gutters>`

You could take a look at the doc [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/#no-gutters).